# The Fundamental group of the circle from "Introduction to knot theory", Ralph H. Fox (1)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

The says in the beginning of discussing this title:

> "Let the field of real numbers be denoted by R and the subring of integers by $J$. We denote the additive subgroup consisting of all integers which are a multiple of 3 by $3J$. The circle, whose fundamental group we propose to calculate, may be regarded as the factor group $R/3J$ with the identification topology, i.e., the largest topology such that the canonical homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow R/3J $ is a continuous mapping.A good way to picture the situation is to regard $R/3J$ as a circle of circumference 3 mounted like a wheel on the real line $R$ so that it may roll freely back and forth without skidding. the possible points of tangency determine the $many-one$ correspondence $\phi$"

And then the book started proving the following:

> The image under $\phi$ of any open subset of $R$ is an open subset of $R/3$ (5.2)

**My Questions:**

1- I have seen the picture of the fundamental group of the circle from "Allen Hatcher" and I have seen the helix of the real line is covering the circle, so how is this related to the upper picture that this book has drawn?

2- What is the importance of proving this: ">The image under $\phi$ of any open subset of $R$ is an open subset of $R/3$"?

Could anyone help me to answer these questions please?

As you can see I am trying to compare the argument followed in "Allen Hatcher" with that followed in this book, so if anyone can give me a comparison, It will be greatly appeciated!

Comment: "What is the importance of proving this" Presumably, they will use it in their next proof, or something thereabouts.

Comment: They said later that the mapping $\phi$ restricted to any interval of $R$ of length < 3 is $1-1$ and  by virtue of  ">The image under $\phi$ of any open subset of $R$ is an open subset of $R/3$ ", is therefore also a homeomorphism on that interval ........ but I do not understand why the map becomes a  homeomorphism on that interval by this @Arthur

Comment: It is continuous. It is 1-1, so it has an inverse function. By this result, this inverse function is also continuous. That's the definition of a homeomorphism.

Comment: The fundamental group of the circle, and of a multitude of other  unions of spaces with non connected intersections, can be computed using a van Kampen theorem for the fundamental groupoid with many base points, e.g. 2 for the circle.. It was dissatisfaction with the standard covering space diversion, which seemed a separate matter,  which led me  to develop this approach,  published in 1967,. It seems the use  of groupoids  in this.  and in covering spaces,  still needs advertising!  Both are  available in the book "Topology and Groupoids". Let the students decide.

Comment: @RonnieBrown Excuse me, sorry  I can not see how is this an answer to my question.

Comment: You are quite right! This was a comment on the context  not an answer. Sometimes that is the way to go in maths.