# The Fundamental group of the circle from "Introduction to knot theory", Ralph H. Fox (3)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

In this book,as a third completion (the second completion I have not asked it yet as I am still writing it) to [The Fundamental group of the circle from "Introduction to knot theory", Ralph H. Fox (1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294054/the-fundamental-group-of-the-circle-from-introduction-to-knot-theory-ralph-h)

The author said:

> "The major step in our derivation of the fundamental group of the circle is the following:
>   (5.4) For any continuous mapping $h: E \rightarrow R/3J$ and real number $x \in R$ such that $\phi(x) = h(0,0)$, there exists one and only one continuous function $\bar{h}: E \rightarrow R$ such that $\bar{h}(0,0) = x$ and $h = \phi \bar{h}$. "

And, then the book started to prove it. where:

$E$ is the rectangle consisting of all pairs $(s,t)$ such that $0 \leq s \leq \sigma $ and $0 \leq t \leq \tau,$ where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two arbitrary non-negative real numbers.

And $R$ is the real numbers and $J$ is the subring of integers.

Is this the equivalent of the path lifting lemma used in "Allen Hatcher"? Or I am wrong? If so what is the correction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not equivalent to the path lifting lemma, however there is a connection: this lifting statement, and the path lifting lemma, are both special cases of the [general lifting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties).

Comment: Would you mind looking at this question please (when you have time) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294054/the-fundamental-group-of-the-circle-from-introduction-to-knot-theory-ralph-h ?